# Changing colours of a div inside if else?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In following code i am trying to upload csv file.its working.what i want to know is how i can change the colour of main-div when csv succesfully uploaded as Green color and when it s not uploaded as red color?

Here is my Code

```
<div id="main-div" class="content bg-gray-lighter">

        <h3 class=" pull-right"><a href="<?php echo $one->assets_folder; ?>/download/sample_csv.csv"><span class="label label-warning"><i class="fa fa-download "></i> Download Sample Format Here <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o "></i> </span></a></h3>
        <?php
        include "../classes/connection.php"; //Connect to Database
        //Upload File
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            $deleterecords = "UPDATE TABLE data"; //empty the table of its current records
            mysql_query($deleterecords);
            $product = $_POST['product'];
            $courier = $_POST['courier'];
            $billmonth = $_POST['billmonth'];
            $billyear = $_POST['billyear'];
            $billrun = $_POST['billrun'];
            $dispatchtype = $_POST['dispatchtype'];
            $Received_Date=$_POST['Received_Date'];

            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {

                echo "<div id='main-div' class='block-content block-content-full bg-success text-white-op'>";
                echo "<p>Displaying contents:</p>";
                echo "<p>Product - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$product. " </strong> Service Provider - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$courier. "</strong> Bill Month - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billmonth. " </strong> Bill Year - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$billyear. "</strong> Bill Run- <strong style='color: #ffc128'>" .$billrun. " </strong> Dispatch Type - <strong style='color: #ffc128'>".$dispatchtype."</strong></p><br/>";
                echo "<span style='color:#feffa4'>";
                readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
                echo "</span>";
            }

            //Import uploaded file to Database
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $linecount++ == count(file('filename.csv'));
                $data[2] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[2]));
                $data[5] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data[5]));

                if (($product==$data[0]) && ($courier==$data[1]) && (strcasecmp($billmonth,$data[6])==0) && ($billyear==$data[7]) && ($billrun==$data[8]) && ($dispatchtype==$data[9])) {

                    $import = "INSERT into data(Product,Courier,Received_Date,Acc_No,Received_By,Delivered_Date,Month,Year,Bill_Run,Dispatch_Type,Status,Bounce_Code) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]','$data[8]','$data[9]','$data[10]','$data[11]')";
                }
                else {

                    echo " <br/> <br/>Data Error.<br/>";
                    echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <br/> <br/>";
                }
                    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        fclose($handle);
            ?>

            <?php
            echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
            print "$linecount Records have been Imported ";
            echo "  <br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-action-undo'></i> Go Back and Upload Again</a> <a href='index.php' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><i class='si si-home'></i> Home</a>  <br/> <br/>";

        //view upload form
         echo "</div>";
        } else {  ?>
```

Comment: There are a million answers to this. But more important appears to be some remark about the base architecture of your code: you should start separating processing of input from creating output. You _first_ process and collect all data from that, _then_ you start creating your output so that you have all data already available. Extra points for starting to put these separate aspects into separate files...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create two CSS classes, one each for successful and unsuccessful uploads. Eg,

```
.uploadSuccess {
 background-color: green;
}

.uploadFail {
 background-color: red;
}
```

Then you can set the class of the div to one of these in either your client or server side code, wherever you make the decision on whether the upload was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be to divide view and logic. Think and read about the [Model View Controller architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

If you want to dot it inline - you just have to fill a variable if the upload was successful (`$bUploadSuccessful = true` for example) and set in relation to that a css-class.

You have to re-format your code to do all the logic before the template is rendered.